# Trouble Plotting With Two Y-Axes in R

Tags: r

I am running the following data to create bollinger bands:

```
library(quantmod)
symbol = "AAPL"
stock_data = getSymbols(symbol,
                    from = "2019-01-01",
                    auto.assign = FALSE)
prices = Cl(stock_data)     
names(prices) = "price"

prices$avg = rollmeanr(prices$price, k=20)    
prices$sd = rollapplyr(prices$price, width = 20, FUN=sd)   
prices$sd2up = prices$avg + 2*prices$sd     
prices$sd2down = prices$avg - 2*prices$sd  
prices$delta_price = prices$price - shift(prices$price, n=1, fill= NA , type="lag")
```

I wanted to plot price, avg, sd2up, and sd2down (which are all on the same y axis), and then include the price changes in the same graph with its own corresponding y-axis (prices being on the right, changes being on the left side). I attempted the following:

```
plot(prices["2020", c("price","avg","sd2up","sd2down")])
par(new=TRUE)
plot(prices["2020", "slope"])
```

I have 0 experience merging graphs and I am aware the syntax is most likely not correct for doing something like this. The plots come out perfectly, but each is separated. Is it because of how I defined the x and y data? I truly appreciate any help with this.